# Stateui Does not update. Could not resolve 'state.signup' from state 'home'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, angularjs-routing

So I've been running into this pretty dumb problem with states lately. I am creating my states with the parent.child state as so:

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/home.html',
    })
    .state('home.signup', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/signup.html',
        url: '/signup',
        controller: "signupController"
    })
  .state('home.login', {
      controller: "loginController",
      templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/login.html',
      url: '/login'
  })
```

My html is as follows:

```
<a ui-sref="home.login"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Login</a>
<a ui-sref="home.signup"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Signup</a>
```

The initial parent state was dashboard instead of home. So dashboard.signup and dashboard.login. I had recently changed this to home.login and home.signup. All works when I go to /home/login and /home/signup, but click on my login link and signup links I get the following error:

```
 Could not resolve 'dashboard.login' from state 'home'
```

I think its still reading the dashboard parent but I have nothing that even relates to it with my login and signup. Everything looks right to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so home.login or dashboard.login?

Comment: I want it to go to home.login but it's going to dashboard.login eventhough i don't have dashboard.login anywhere in my js.

Comment: Did an entire solution search already lol...

Comment: So I was able to get it to work. All I did was restart my computer... Not sure why that is the problem. If you might have an explanation for that it would be great to know. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you check $state.go,what is the state you mentioned in your controller.

Comment: So I was able to get it to work. All I did was restart my computer... Not sure why that is the problem. If you might have an explanation for that it would be great to know. Thanks anyways